# MVC Spring : Can we get the XML response if I passed json parameters in body for post request?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, soap

I did the google around it but I got few link which is described, we cannot get the XML response if passed parameters as body for post request. Please confirm, Is it possible in spring? If yes please share the annotation or any related hint then I can look forward on it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your Endpoint ? Are you sure this is soap message you are handling ? since you have soap tag

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RequestMapping annotation. It does have *produces* element that specifies the type of the returned response. If you like to force XML as return type you could use something like that

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someresource", 
                method=RequestMethod.POST, 
                produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
```

Another example - if you like to consume only JSON and XML, but you like to return XML:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someresource", 
                method=RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON},
                produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
```

Comment: Thanks Plamen for quick response. I am using spring 3.0.4 and consumes/produces are not available for @RequestMapping in 3.0.x
can you suggest me for version 3.0.4?

Comment: @Summy Maybe the _MarshallingView_ can help. Here is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/) . Also I didn't notice the SOAP tag the first time - you receive SOAP message with JSON payload?